# how do i send a user message to their mail from phpmailer?

Tags: php, jquery

> Hi guys, please I'm having problem with my code. I want to accept user
>   email and verify it from my database then send the user an email using
>   PHPMailer but it's giving me error, I guess I did some bunch of error
>   coding here. please how do I go about it? this question might be silly
>   but I really need assistance from anyone, please. Thanks.
>
> here is what I've tried out.

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password007","voting");
   session_start();

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      // username and password sent from form 

      $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);

      $sql = "SELECT VotersID,Email,First_name FROM voters WHERE Email = '$email' ";
      $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

     $votersID = $row['VotersID'];
 $first = $row['First_name'];

      if($count == 1) {

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '******@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '*******';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = '587';

$mail->From = '*****@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'West End University College';
$mail->addAddress($email, $first);

$mail->addReplyTo('*****@gmail.com', 'West End University College');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;
$mail->isHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'code for login Confirmation';
$mail->Body    = 'Hi, your code is:';
$mail->addAttachment($votersID); 

      }
if(!$mail->send())  {  

    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
      }
       else{
           echo "Message sent successfully";
       }
   }
    ?>
```

Errors :

> Notice: Undefined variable: mail in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\voters\accConfirm.php on line 45 Fatal error: Call to
>   a member function send() on null in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\voters\accConfirm.php on line 45

Comment: you forgot to write down the error you are gettiing

Comment: Hide your password man.......

Comment: And whats the error message

Comment: Try adding $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;      and post the error message

Comment: if(!$mail->send()) {  
          
     echo 'Message could not be sent.';
       echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
       exit;
          }

Comment: it is not reading that error, when the email is entered wrongly or invalid, this is the error message I'm getting from the background. Notice: Undefined variable: mail in C:\xampp\htdocs\voters\accConfirm.php on line 45

Fatal error: Call to a member function send() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\voters\accConfirm.php on line 45    @MasivuyeCokile